# How to know what preposition to use

Tags: prepositions

Say I want to use the word *cliffhanger* in a sentence.

> The show ended **on** a cliffhanger.

Or,

> The show ended **at** a cliffhanger.

Not just this sentence; how do I know what is the correct preposition to use at what phase of a sentence?

Comment: How about `The show ended with a cliffhanger.`? :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought of adding that too, did not sound good to me? :P

Comment: But feel free to add that to the cloud of confusion.

Comment: I guess I'm just as curious as you are on that! I think I've been using 'with' for a long time, and it just sounds better in my mind ^^

Comment: Sometimes I'll be going on with a witty remark that would totally get me the control of argument, and then I'd start thinking to myself, if I used the prepositions correctly or not.

Comment: The show can end *on* a high or a low note.  It can end *with* a whimper, bang or cliffhanger.  Or it can end *at* 3pm on November 22nd.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ended+*+cliffhanger%22&oq=%22ended+*+cliffhanger%22

Comment: Why not *in* for that matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that specific case, "with" is the way to go because it's a happening.

Ended with a cliffhanger. Ended with a murder. Ended with a long, wet kiss.

As opposed to a noun

Ended on a cliff. Ended in a swimming pool.

There it's just a matter of figuring out what you do with each sort of thing. On a cliff versus in a swimming pool, for example.

Comment: What if I take a different case. And then something else. 
How do I know for sure, what to use?

Comment: Ok, I think I got a bit more understanding this time. :)

Comment: :) This stuff is messy — language as a whole is messy. It's always been more useful to me as a writer to just stop and ask myself if what I'm doing makes sense and feels right. Hard and fast rules for this stuff exist, but they change with context and intent to the point that it's different almost case-by-case. In the immortal words of the Internet, "ain't nobody got time for that."

Comment: Coming from a writer, Those words are really encouraging. :)

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your fundamental question of ***How do I know what is the correct preposition to use at what phase of a sentence?***, I'm afraid that the answer is simply *by learning English* or *by experience*. English doesn't have simple rules to follow!

Comment: Have you been on the fine beer that our country produces Trevor?

Comment: @Sam  Which country is that?

Comment: despite lacking references this is the answer which gets right to the point and gets the point right.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of being unpopular - every narration on television that I have heard (in this context) has said "the show ended ***on*** a cliffhanger".  So that is the only phrase I hear in usage for TV shows, but that is not to say it is the "best".

That is my tuppence worth.